# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Два года(,) как нет его с нами"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сложное-предложение

*Два года(,) как нет его с нами.*

Ученица поставила запятую, обосновав тем, что предложение сложное. Ей исправили, убрав запятую. Почему? Что не так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, учительница не права.

Из [**Розенталя:**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137)

> § 33. Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного
>   предложения
>
> <…>
>
> 2. В составе сложноподчиненного предложения могут быть неполные предложения: 1) неполное предложение в качестве главной части: *Вот
>      уже два года, как мы женаты* (ср.: *Мы женаты вот уже два года* —
>      простое предложение); *Уже месяц, как он вернулся с юга* (ср.: *Он уже
>      месяц как вернулся с юга* — запятая перед союзом как «оторвала» бы
>      сказуемое от подлежащего); *Уже три недели, как мы здесь* (ср.: *Мы
>      уже три недели как здесь* — обстоятельство места выражено сочетанием
>      как здесь).

Comment: Да вот я тоже так думаю, а как девочке объяснить? Она увидела неполное предложение, а учительница нет.

Comment: Наверное, надо спросить учительницу, почему она его не видит.

Comment: @Людмила, а почему девочки просто не показать справочник учительнице ?