# "Энный год как"

Tags: запятые, как

Не могу понять, нужна ли запятая перед "как" в следующем предложении:

> Я уже второй год как сюда переехал.

В Нацкорпусе много таких примеров без запятой, и я уже хотел было просто спросить, почему запятая не нужна, но наткнулся на это:

> **Вопрос № 283758**
>
> Подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед "как"? И почему. А сегодня год, как мы вместе.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Запятая нужна. Она ставится между главным и придаточным предложением в составе сложноподчиненного. При этом в главной части предложение неполное (подразумевается: *с того момента).* В справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя «Пунктуация» предложениям такого типа посвящен отдельный пункт, ср. примеры из справочника: *Вот уже два года, как мы женаты. Уже месяц, как он вернулся с юга. Уже три недели, как мы здесь.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Я уже второй год как сюда переехал.**

В справочнике Розенталя поясняется, что запятая в таком случае не нужна, поскольку это простое предложение, а не сложное. В приведенных в ответе Грамоты примерах "в главной части предложения подразумевались слова *прошло с того времени* или *прошло с того момента"* (цитирую по Розенталю).

Comment: Спасибо! А вы процитировать не можете или ссылку дать? Мне изначально и казалось интуитивно, что она не нужна. Задумался над этим вчера утром, когда увидел в книжке запятую в подобном примере со вторым годом, но сразу подумал, что она там лишняя.

Comment: В ответе [на этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447509/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8?rq=1) есть нужная ссылка.

Comment: Спасибо, нашёл!